# Opengl 3.2: How to use texture atlas?

Tags: opengl

For now, I've been rendering my skybox as a 6 different quads with 6 different textures and 6 VBOs, but I really want to merge them into 1 cube with 1 VBO, so I tried to use texture atlas and Im having a problem with it. When I try to setup only 1 piece of texture file with ST coordinates (is it correct way?) I get whole atlas loaded as a texture of each side.

This is ST coords for front side(I have 4x4 atlas which size is 4096x4096):

```
(0.25f, 0); //left top!
(0.5f, 0); //right top!
(0.5f, 0.25f); //right down!
(0.25f, 0.25f); //left down!
```

Can someone explain me how to create multitextured object (for example a cube) please? 
What extra code should I include to mine, instead of usual "one texture - one object" render ?

Comment: Texture atlasing is not multitexturing. Multitexturing would be if you'd process several textures into each rendered fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a cubemap texture? It's one single texture with the topology of a cube and you can even double use the cube's vertex positions as texture coordinates.

Comment: Because I am noob in OpenGL and I cant find any concrete explanations on the web...